# iOS can't receive notifications in react-native-firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, apple-push-notifications, react-native-firebase

I am using `react-native-firebase` along with some another libraries to display notifications which comes from Firebase. Here is how my `package.json` looks like.

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "react-native-push-notification": "^7.2.3",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.8.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^11.4.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^11.4.1",
    ...
}
```

In some reasons my application doesn't receive notifications at all on iOS devices. Even test notifications from Firebase Console which sends by device token doesn't work. So i make a suggestion that my problem is not in the `react-native` code. By the way notifications works on Android as they should.

In my "Signing & Capabilities" tab from XCode the Push Notifications are enabled and both Background fetch and Remote Notifications background modes are enabled too.

Here is my `AppDelegate.m`

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import <Firebase.h>
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>
#import <RNCPushNotificationIOS.h>

#import <AppCenterReactNative.h>
#import <AppCenterReactNativeAnalytics.h>
#import <AppCenterReactNativeCrashes.h>

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import <TSBackgroundFetch/TSBackgroundFetch.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  if ([FIRApp defaultApp] == nil) {
    [FIRApp configure];
  }
  [AppCenterReactNative register];
  [AppCenterReactNativeAnalytics registerWithInitiallyEnabled:true];
  [AppCenterReactNativeCrashes registerWithAutomaticProcessing];
  [[TSBackgroundFetch sharedInstance] didFinishLaunching];

  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                   moduleName:@"ModuleName"
                                            initialProperties:nil];

  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

  // Define UNUserNotificationCenter
  UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
  center.delegate = self;

  return YES;
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

// Required for the register event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
 [RNCPushNotificationIOS didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken];
}
// Required for the notification event. You must call the completion handler after handling the remote notification.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}
// Required for the registrationError event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
 [RNCPushNotificationIOS didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:error];
}
// Required for localNotification event
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler
{
  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveNotificationResponse:response];
}

//Called when a notification is delivered to a foreground app.
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
        willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void
        (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler
{
  completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionSound | UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert | UNNotificationPresentationOptionBadge);
}

@end
```

And my `info.plist`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>BGTaskSchedulerPermittedIdentifiers</key>
    <array>
        <string>com.transistorsoft.fetch</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>App name</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>app.bundle.identifier</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>app.bundle.name</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.2.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)</string>
    <key>ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption</key>
    <false/>
    <key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
    <string>9.0</string>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>localhost</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSAppleMusicUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Allow the app access music.</string>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app requires access to the camera. You can make photos to attach to reports or to update your avatar.</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app requires access to the user’s location information to search nearby units and buidings.</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app requires access to the user’s location information to search nearby units and buidings.</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app requires access to the photo library. You can select photos to attach to reports or to update your avatar.</string>
    <key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>Montserrat-Bold.ttf</string>
        <string>Montserrat-Light.ttf</string>
        <string>Montserrat-Regular.ttf</string>
        <string>SFProDisplay-Bold.otf</string>
        <string>SFProDisplay-Light.otf</string>
        <string>SFProDisplay-Medium.otf</string>
        <string>SFProDisplay-Regular.otf</string>
        <string>SFProDisplay-Semibold.otf</string>
        <string>SFProDisplay-Thin.otf</string>
        <string>SFProText -Regular.otf</string>
        <string>SFProText-Bold.otf</string>
        <string>SFProText-Light.otf</string>
        <string>SFProText-Medium.otf</string>
        <string>SFProText-Semibold.otf</string>
        <string>SFProText-Thin.otf</string>
        <string>AntDesign.ttf</string>
        <string>Entypo.ttf</string>
        <string>EvilIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>Feather.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome5_Regular.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf</string>
        <string>Foundation.ttf</string>
        <string>Ionicons.ttf</string>
        <string>MaterialIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>SimpleLineIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>Octicons.ttf</string>
        <string>Zocial.ttf</string>
        <string>Fontisto.ttf</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fetch</string>
        <string>processing</string>
        <string>remote-notification</string>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Why might this be happening?

*P.S. Bundle identifiers, app identifiers or module name are replaced with placeholders*

Comment: Have you setup the APN(Apple Push Notification) in firebase console? Please check here. `Firebase Console -> Project Settings -> Cloud Messaging (Tab)` You need to setup the APN Auth key there.

You may also test it on physical device.

Comment: @ErickMaeda yes. The APNs Authentication Key is included to project, but I'm not sure if it's valid. Are there ways to check if I don't have access to developer.apple.com?

Comment: Have you tested in physical device ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a problem with incorrect APNs certificate. I have changed it in firebase console and it works now! :)

Answer (score -1):

any thing is ok, only add blew code in file AppDelegate.h

#import <Firebase.h>

Comment: in file AppDelegate.h