# React native firebase iOS push notifcations not receiving,

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification

I'm using react-native-firebase to get push notifications to my app, everything works perfeclty in android app but in ios I'm getting only firbase token only. Using that firebase token I send push notifications to my device but not a single notification getting my device.

My AppDelegate.mm as follow,

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <Firebase.h>

#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>

#import <AppCenterReactNative.h>
#import <AppCenterReactNativeAnalytics.h>
#import <AppCenterReactNativeCrashes.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  [FIRApp configure];
  self.moduleName = @"CompelloInvoiceApproval";
  // You can add your custom initial props in the dictionary below.
  // They will be passed down to the ViewController used by React Native.
  self.initialProps = @{};
  
  [AppCenterReactNative register];
  [AppCenterReactNativeAnalytics registerWithInitiallyEnabled:true];
  [AppCenterReactNativeCrashes registerWithAutomaticProcessing];

  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

- (BOOL) application: (UIApplication *)application
             openURL: (NSURL *)url
             options: (NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey, id> *) options
{
  if ([self.authorizationFlowManagerDelegate resumeExternalUserAgentFlowWithURL:url]) {
    return YES;
  }
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:options];
}

- (BOOL) application: (UIApplication *) application
continueUserActivity: (nonnull NSUserActivity *)userActivity
  restorationHandler: (nonnull void (^)(NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> * _Nullable))restorationHandler
{
  if ([userActivity.activityType isEqualToString:NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb]) {
    if (self.authorizationFlowManagerDelegate) {
      BOOL resumableAuth = [self.authorizationFlowManagerDelegate resumeExternalUserAgentFlowWithURL:userActivity.webpageURL];
      if (resumableAuth) {
        return YES;
      }
    }
  }
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application continueUserActivity:userActivity restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
}


- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index"];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

@end
```

and my info.plist as follow,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>Compello</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleGetInfoString</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(MARKETING_VERSION)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>com.compello.approval</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.compello</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)</string>
    <key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>localhost</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Your app needs access to your camera to capture images.</string>
    <key>NSDocumentsFolderUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Your app needs access to the Documents folder</string>
    <key>NSHumanReadableCopyright</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Allow access to the photo library for selecting images</string>
    <key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>Fontisto.ttf</string>
        <string>Foundation.ttf</string>
        <string>Ionicons.ttf</string>
        <string>MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>MaterialIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>Octicons.ttf</string>
        <string>SimpleLineIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>Zocial.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome5_Regular.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf</string>
        <string>AntDesign.ttf</string>
        <string>Entypo.ttf</string>
        <string>EvilIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>Feather.ttf</string>
        <string>Mulish.ttf</string>
        <string>Mulish-Bold.ttf</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fetch</string>
        <string>remote-notification</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>Launch</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Can some help me sort out this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1 :
https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/7074

Solution 2 :
https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/4803

Solution 3 :
[iOS can't receive notifications in react-native-firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68314803/ios-cant-receive-notifications-in-react-native-firebase)

Solution 4 :
Handle Notifications in AppDelegate

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <Firebase.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
        // Handle the received notification
        NSLog(@"Received notification: %@", userInfo);
    
        // Add your custom handling code here
    
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
    }
    
    // Add other necessary methods if not present (e.g didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken)
    
    @end
```

Solution 5 :
Request User Permission

```
- (void)registerForRemoteNotifications {
    UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge | UNAuthorizationOptionSound)
                          completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (granted) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
            });
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Notification permission denied");
        }
    }];
}
```

Solution 6 :
Check Device Token:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    const unsigned *tokenBytes = [deviceToken bytes];
    NSString *deviceTokenString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x",
                                   ntohl(tokenBytes[0]), ntohl(tokenBytes[1]), ntohl(tokenBytes[2]),
                                   ntohl(tokenBytes[3]), ntohl(tokenBytes[4]), ntohl(tokenBytes[5]),
                                   ntohl(tokenBytes[6]), ntohl(tokenBytes[7])];

    // Send deviceTokenString to your server or Firebase Cloud Messaging
}
```

Comment: Non of them not working